# PVC leak-free joints without glue

Tags: pvc, joints

I am interested in installing a PVC tubing conduction (80 mm diameter, no longer than 1 m.), with two 90 degree joints.

I am planning to conduct a experiment in which inside the tube, a sponge-like material wick will conduct water. However, it is extremely important to avoid any kind of contamination (usually glues tend to release even small amounts of solvents/salts), and that is why I am searching for mechanical options to properly seal the elbows.

I would like to know if there is a way to fix the joints without the use of glues of any kind, instead I am interested in mechanical methods like o-rings or threads, the conduction will not be under pressure and it will not conduct water at full capacity, it will conduce a small amount of cold water.

Comment: I guess you need to use pipe that large for a specific reason?  Smaller pipe might give you more fitting options.

Comment: You could use RTV silicone as long as there won't be any pressure in the line

Comment: Indeed, I am planning to conduct a experiment in which inside the tube, a sponge-like material wick will conduct water. However, it is extremely important to avoid any kind of contamination (usually glues tend to release even small amounts of solvents/salts), and that is why I am searching for mechanical options to properly seal the elbows. I highly appreciate your answers.

Comment: Embedded the explanation of the need, taken from a comment, into the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably use Flex Couplings like these:

[image]

To connect a pipe to an elbow, you'd have to find a coupling
which fits both the outside diameter of the pipe, as well as the outside diameter of the elbow.
Something like this one might be flexible enough to both stretch over the elbow and still clamp tightly onto the pipe:
[image]
https://www.plasticpipeshop.co.uk/75-89mm-EPDM-Adaptor_p_6140.html
or otherwise possibly one of the reducing versions which have a different size on each side.

Comment: I've seen flex elbows in smaller sizes (like 40mm, 1 1/2"), but not sure if they have them for 80mm pipe.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - good point - I'll improve my suggestion a little ...

Answer (score 0):

PVC is available in threaded varities. I've seen it mostly in landscape irrigation systems, so it can handle domestic water pressures.